# React native cloud functions logs empty

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

I was trying cloud functions today, followed the docs and got it to deploy successfully but the logs will always be empty.

I am using RN firebase client SDK from this website

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/functions/reference/functions

```
 "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.0",
}
```

This is my function code :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    console.log('hello world');
 response.send("Hello from Firebase yo!");
});
```

this is my dashboard screen shot:
[image: firebse dashboard]

this is my logs screen shot:
[image]

Did i miss anything ?

Comment: How are you trying to invoke that function?

Comment: @DougStevenson i used 'firebase deploy --only functions' command from terminal

Comment: That won't invoke anything.  That will just deploy the function and make it available to be invoked later.

Comment: @DougStevenson  by invoke, do you mean this  ? 

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    console.log('hello world');
 response.send("Hello from Firebase yo!");
});

Comment: No, that's the code you deployed.  You need to invoke it with an http request.

Comment: aah i see, got it @DougStevenson. for those who has the same problem as me,

what i did was i invoke open the url like this

https://us-central1-jokii-debug.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld